# Text input sanitation and security

Tags: php, security, xss

I am trying to make sure all my inputs are secure, protecting the server and XSS attacks.  Is validating input with `strip_tags` and `htmlentities` a fool proof system?  I have been told it was and would like to confirm.  ie for example:

```
$re = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['re']), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

this should prevent any linux commands and any html links correct? are there any vulnerabilities that havent been considered with this?

Comment: "linux commands"? This one expression doesn't fit into the context. Tell us more about it.

Comment: What i have in mind is something such as ";ls -la"

Comment: Why do you care if that stuff ends up in either the DB or the browser? You don't do a `passthru($user_input)`, do you?!

Comment: no i do not, so it would only be interpreted as text then?

Comment: It's only interpreted by *you* (and the user's browser, if you send it there), so I can't tell you. But sure it won't be executed as a shell command *automatically*.

Comment: people have become so paranoid they apply every function to every string.

Comment: You need to stop throwing random functions at random strings and actually learn **what you're trying to protect against** before you write another line of code. I guarantee you're missing ten vulnerabilities for every one you think you're fixing. You can't just throw these functions at your code after the fact and expect to produce a secure system.

Comment: hardly, arbitrarily applying functions with out understanding is more dangerous, than doing nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not at all what `htmlentities` is for. Use `htmlentites` to encode your output before it is sent to the browser. It has nothing to do with sanitizing input. The only thing you need to worry about when processing input is properly escaping data being interpolated into SQL queries to prevent SQL injection. See [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for more on that.

`strip_tags` is debatably useful here, but you don't need to use both `strip_tags` *and* `htmlentities`. The whole purpose of `htmlentites` is that it prevents the tags from being interpreted. The only correct way to think about this is: Preserve the content the user entered and render it safe. Don't strip their tags, just *encode* them so they appear as they were typed. Otherwise you wind up stripping things like `<sarcasm>` and `<rant>` tags. The intent of the user was not to inject HTML.

"Linux commands" have nothing to do with HTML. There is no way to execute arbitrary Linux commands through HTML/script injection.

> What i have in mind is something such as ";ls -la"

If you are actually taking user-supplied input and executing it via [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or something in that vein, you are already in trouble. This is a terrible idea and you shouldn't do it.

</rant>

Comment: "encoding" to be safe to output to the browser **is** sanitizing

Comment: There is no sanitizing going on here, unless his server-side application is somehow executing JavaScript. "Sanitizing" by stripping HTML on input is meaningless and *wrong*, every bit as much as "sanitizing" your output by encoding double quotes to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @zerkms: It's sanitizing, but it's not sensible at the point of time where this seems to be happening.

Comment: No, it is not sanitizing. You might as well argue that stripping the letter "B" from your input to protect from space aliens is a form of "sanitizing". It doesn't make sense. He isn't protecting anything from anything, he's only corrupting his data.

Comment: okay if that's not sensible, what should the approach to sanitizing the input be?

Comment: @JimmyBanks That depends *entirely* on what you're doing with the input. Are you writing it to a text file? Don't do anything with it. Are you writing it to a database? Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and it will sanitize your input for you. Do you intend to convert it to a number and use it in some kind of math? Scrub out non-numeric characters. Context is everything. Sanitizing data is about making sure your data is in the format you expect it to be in.

Comment: @meagar: sanitizing is a process of making some arbitrary input valid according some language-based rules. This is my definition of that term. So `htmlentities` **is** sanitizing a string to be shown in browser. If not agree - give another definition.

Comment: @zerkms I agree with your definition, and I agree that he is **attempting** to sanitize his input, but again, *as I said*, using `htmlentities` **is not sanitizing his input**. It is not rendering his input sanitized. It is no more or less sanitized than it was before the function call. It may still contain SQL injections, and "linux commands" if he is passing the input on to `system`. In the context of the web, `htmlentities` is about sanitizing *output*, and there is no indication that he's going to be outputting this query string parameter.

Comment: @meagar: It's a form of sanitization if it's going to be sent to a browser anytime after, which seems to be the case here. That doesn't mean it's completely *safe* or it shouldn't better be done at a different point in time, though.

Comment: @meagar: indeed, but I don't see anything about db in the original question. Anyway, as long as you agree with my definition - I have nothing else to say and discuss about, +1 ;-)

Comment: @Niklas B.: from the question I don't see anything about when it is applied and database. So I assume OP wants to do that right before sending it to the client.

Comment: @zerkms Admittedly, I made the assumption that there would be a database involved. What else would he be doing with a query string parameter except using it to look up some record?

Comment: @meagar: he may look up in files or using Facebook API ;-)

Comment: @meagar: How would you output the user's input on the page? Say, in the `input` field?

Comment: @zerkms I would use `htmlentities`. This is the express intent. To encode your output and render any HTML code harmless. As I've said, context is everything. In this context, accessing the query string, the intent is obviously to *do* something with the value, and that something is almost certainly not to echo it back to the user and quit. `htmlentities` should be the very *very* last thing you do with a variable right before it is `echo`'d to the browser.

Answer (score 4):

You must always choose the right tool for the job.   That being said `$re = htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['re']), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");`  should never be used for anything.  The command is redundant which means you don't understand what its doing. It not very good at preventing xss because [xss is an output problem](https://sitewat.ch/en/Blog/5).

To sanitize shell arguments you must use [escpaeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).  For XSS you should use:
`htmlspecialchars($_GET['re'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`. However this doesn't stop all XSS and it doesn't do anything to stop SQL Injection.

Use parametrized queries for sql.

And all of that just scratches the surface read the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main).

Comment: why use `ENT_QUOTES` and `"UTF-8"` as arguments? The first seems to be useless, while the latter seems to be the default.

Comment: @Niklas B. Very good question.  The first command is because quote marks alone can be used to exploit XSS vulnerabilities (see: xss is an output problem).  The UTF-8 is for compatibility,  if the input string is UTF-8 then the return'ed string will be null without this argument.

Comment: I think the first one is only an issue if you insert the output into some kind of incomplete HTML structure. Quotes without brackets (`<`/`>`) can hardly be used to modify the DOM. Can you give an example how unescaped quote marks alone would be a vulnerability?

Comment: @Niklas B. Most incorrect, 
`<input type=text value='<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET[v])?>' />`.  PoC:  ?e=' onclick=alert(1),  read: xss is an output problem in my post.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with incomplete HTML structure. Thanks for the clarification. Still I wouldn't recommend `ENT_QUOTES` in the case where you're *not* outputting inside an attribute value.

Comment: @Niklas B.  Did you know that the value in this case is automatically de-ent_quoted on submission?  Also,  no there is nothing here about "incomplete structures",  if you think this is the case then you missed the PoC in its entirety.  If at any point you print out a value within a HTML tag you can probably inject an event handler.

Comment: Yeah, but if you *don't* output a value inside an HTML tag (or more specifically, inside an attribute value, which is the only case I can imagine this to be sensible), the `ENT_QUOTES` would simply be double quoting. You should always know what you're doing and how your output will be interpreted and choose the quoting appropriately.

Comment: @Niklas B.  Once again,  **No**,  ENT_QUOTES converts quote marks into their HTML entity equivalent.  So if its not within a tag the user sees the quote literal,  just as they would see a `<` instead of `&lt;`.  This is form of escaping,  that is what this function does after all.

Comment: Yes, the term "double quoting" wasn't quite correct. Still, using the same argument it would not be a bad idea to replace *every single character* with its corresponding HTML entity. I wouldn't like to see this as output either, even though it's valid. I think we should agree to disagree, this discussion isn't very fruitful.

Comment: @Niklas B. Nope,  I think you need to spend more time studying XSS.  Google has payed out a lot of money for this exact issue.  You should understand it or you will be burned by it.  Acunetix and http://sitewat.ch will detect this type of xss.

Comment: Please enlighten me. The example you've given isn't quite fitting IMHO, because it only applies for output inside HTML attribute values (which bears other issues like `javascript:` schemes in URLs and such, that also aren't prevented by `htmlspecialchars` with `ENT_QUOTES`). However, I heard about the Google XSS bounties, and my understanding of them was that the more tricky ones are due to UTF-8 decoding issues inside the sanitization routines. If you can provide some material/reference, that'd be nice. We're all here to learn from each other, after all, at least that's why I visit this site.

Comment: @Niklas B. So i am typing on a laptop given to me by Google for being in the top 1% of their web app bug bounty program.  The most common type of vulnerability was this exact one that i am describing.  Some variations are that the output was already within an event handler or within a JS tag, but the root was the same.  They where not properly handling quote marks.  The 2nd most common vuln was HTTP Response Splitting.   To track down these issues I wrote my own scanner from scratch and I am selling this service: http://sitewatch.me. Blog posts are only written about the most interesting flaws

Comment: I don't deny that this is an issue. I also won't argue about the effectiveness of your service. What I can argue about, though, is the fact that the naive attempt of adding `ENT_QUOTES` to the `htmlspecialchars` is no more a magic pill than any other general-purpose output sanitization function is. In every case, you specifically need to analyse exactly how the value you output will be interpreted by the browser. In the very critical case where you output inside an HTML attribute, you need to handle the quote issue, but you also need to handle stuff like sanitizing URLs or Javascript or ...

Comment: @Niklas B. aaah and that's where we agree.   XSS is an output problem,  its highly dependent on where the output is within the HTML.  I agree,  even ENT_QUOTES won't stop you from `<a href=javascript:alert(1)>`  or output within an event handler.

Comment: Good. I was starting to doubt my supposed understanding of XSS. Well, at the end of the day I've learned a slightly different way to look at it, so that's nice. Always enjoy the discussion with smart people here on SO.

Comment: @Niklas B.  That resonates with me.  There is always something interesting to learn from SO.

Answer (score -1):

this is how I filter my inputs before I'll insert it into my database

```
 <?php
      function sanitize($data){
          $result = trim($data);
          $result = htmlspecialchars($data);
          $result = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
          return $result;
      }
 ?>
```